# Predictions for tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc distributed uniformly?

Tags: tensorflow

The [TensorFlow documentation for tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_auc) mentions the following:

> For best results, predictions should be distributed approximately
>   uniformly in the range [0, 1] and not peaked around 0 or 1. The
>   quality of the AUC approximation may be poor if this is not the case.

I am a bit confused because I feel like a common paradigm is to have `predictions` be compared against a target 1-hot encoding:

```
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    last_fully_connected_layer,
    num_outputs=2,
    activation_fn=None)
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(target, logits)

# I believe this yields a 3-vector with all 0s but a 1 at 1 single position.
predictions = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
```

In those cases, the `predictions` tensor contains all 0s or 1s.

Should we avoid using `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc` in those cases? I am not sure in what cases we would use `tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc` then.

Comment: Actually ... what does it mean for prediction values to fall within [0, 1] anyway? Why would a classifier make in-between predictions?